What does this triangle rasterization code do? What does it use a “depth cueing table” for?
Who can explain to me what is the depthq_table, how is it built, how the function works gtmap_persp32_fp, how arranged perspective correction every 32 pixels in this function? That is, as I understand it, this is a palette of 256 colors, and 33 shades of these colors in brightness – this is depthq_table, am I right?
char depthq_table[33][256]; // depth cueing tables, precalculated and loaded from game level file

/*****************************************************************************
 *              Draw Gouraud Shaded Texture Map Perspective-Correct
 ****************************************************************************/
void    draw_poly_gtmap_persp( sint16 *iptr )
{
    if ( xgen_xguvpersp_fp(iptr+1) )
        gtmap_persp32_fp( xgen_ymin, xgen_ymax, (unsigned char*)texture_page_ptrs[*(iptr)] );
}

int     xgen_xguvpersp_fp( sint16 *iptr )
{
    UVGP_INFO       *ptr1,*ptr2;
    XBUF_PERSP_FP   *xptr;
    int             g,g_add;
    int             x,x_add;
    float scale;
    float           uoz,uoz_add;
    float           voz,voz_add;
    float           ooz,ooz_add;
    int             y1,y2,ydif;
    int             min_y,max_y;
    int             numcoords;


    numcoords = (int)*(iptr++);                         // Get Number Coords
    ptr2 = (UVGP_INFO *)iptr;
    ptr1 = ptr2 + numcoords-1;
    min_y = max_y = ptr1->ys;
    for ( ;numcoords>0;numcoords--,ptr1=ptr2,ptr2++ )   // For All Side in Clockwise manner
    {
        y1 = ptr1->ys;
        y2 = ptr2->ys;
        if ( y1<y2 )                                    // We are on RHS of Polygon
        {
            if ( y1<min_y )
                min_y = y1;

            ydif = y2-y1;

            x = ptr1->xs;
            x_add = ((ptr2->xs-x)<<16)/ydif;
            x = (x<<16) + 0x0ffff;

            g = ptr1->shade<<8;                         // Get Lerps and Deltas
            scale = 1.0f/ydif;
            g_add = ((ptr2->shade<<8) - g)/ydif;
            uoz = ptr1->uoz;
            uoz_add = (ptr2->uoz - uoz) * scale;
            voz = ptr1->voz;
            voz_add = (ptr2->voz - voz) * scale;
            ooz = ptr1->ooz;
            ooz_add = (ptr2->ooz - ooz) * scale;

            xptr = ((XBUF_PERSP_FP *)xbuffer) + y1;
            for ( ;y1<y2;y1++,xptr++ )
            {
                x += x_add;
                g += g_add;
                uoz += uoz_add;
                voz += voz_add;
                ooz += ooz_add;
                xptr->Xright = x;
                xptr->Gright = g;
                xptr->UOZright = uoz;
                xptr->VOZright = voz;
                xptr->OOZright = ooz;
            }
        }
        else if ( y2<y1 )                               // We are on LHS of Polygon
        {
            if ( y1>max_y )
                max_y = y1;

            ydif = y1-y2;

            x = ptr2->xs;
            x_add = ((ptr1->xs-x)<<16)/ydif;
            x = (x<<16) + 0x0001;

            g = ptr2->shade<<8;                         // Get Lerps and Deltas
            scale = 1.0f/ydif;
            g_add = ((ptr1->shade<<8) - g)/ydif;
            uoz = ptr2->uoz;
            uoz_add = (ptr1->uoz - uoz) * scale;
            voz = ptr2->voz;
            voz_add = (ptr1->voz - voz) * scale;
            ooz = ptr2->ooz;
            ooz_add = (ptr1->ooz - ooz) * scale;

            xptr = ((XBUF_PERSP_FP *)xbuffer) + y2;
            for ( ;y2<y1;y2++,xptr++ )
            {
                x += x_add;
                g += g_add;
                uoz += uoz_add;
                voz += voz_add;
                ooz += ooz_add;
                xptr->Xleft = x;
                xptr->Gleft = g;
                xptr->UOZleft = uoz;
                xptr->VOZleft = voz;
                xptr->OOZleft = ooz;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( min_y==max_y )
        return(0);
    xgen_ymin = min_y;              // Insert Global Y bounds..
    xgen_ymax = max_y;
    return(1);
}

/******************************************************************************
 *                         TextureMapper
 *              Perspective Correction every 32 Pixels
 *****************************************************************************/
void    gtmap_persp32_fp( int ymin, int ymax, unsigned char *tptr )
{
    /* This version does 32 pixels at a time linearly, and adaptively double pixels for each 32 pixel span.
        Should only be used in 640x480 though */
    XBUF_PERSP_FP   *dataptr;
    unsigned char   *lineptr,*pixptr;
    float               ooz,uoz,voz,scale;
    float               oozadd32,uozadd32,vozadd32;
    int             start_g,add_g,add_g2;
    int             end_u,end_v;
    int             start_u,start_v;
    int             add_u,add_v;
    int             start_x,end_x;
    int             x;

    dataptr = ((XBUF_PERSP_FP *)xbuffer)+ymin;
    lineptr = (unsigned char*)phd_winptr + ( ymin*phd_scrwidth );
    for (ymax-=ymin; ymax>0; ymax--, dataptr++, lineptr+=phd_scrwidth)
    {
        start_x = dataptr->Xleft >> 16;
        end_x = dataptr->Xright >> 16;
        x = end_x - start_x;
        if (x <= 0)
            continue;
        
        if ( x>32 )
        {
            start_g = dataptr->Gleft;
            add_g = (dataptr->Gright-start_g) / x;
            add_g2 = add_g<<1;

            scale = 32.0f/x;
            uoz = dataptr->UOZleft;
            uozadd32 = (dataptr->UOZright-uoz) * scale;
            voz = dataptr->VOZleft;
            vozadd32 = (dataptr->VOZright-voz) * scale;
            ooz = dataptr->OOZleft;
            oozadd32 = (dataptr->OOZright-ooz) * scale;

            scale = 256.0f/ooz;
            end_u = (int)(uoz * scale);
            end_v = (int)(voz * scale);

            pixptr = lineptr + start_x;
        
            ooz += oozadd32;
            scale = 256.0f/ooz;
            
            for ( ; x>=32; x-=32)
            {
                start_u = end_u;
                uoz += uozadd32;
                end_u = (int)(uoz*scale);
                add_u = (end_u-start_u)>>5;

                start_v = end_v;
                voz += vozadd32;
                end_v = (int)(voz*scale);
                add_v = (end_v-start_v)>>5;

                // FP divide in parallel with the pixel drawing
                ooz += oozadd32;
                scale = 256.0f/ooz;

                if ((ABS(add_u) + ABS(add_v)) & SINGLE_MASK)
                {
                    // Single pixel it
                    *(pixptr) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+1) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+2) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+3) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+4) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+5) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+6) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+7) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+8) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+9) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+10) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+11) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+12) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+13) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+14) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+15) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_g += add_g;
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;

                    *(pixptr+16) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+17) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+18) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+19) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+20) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+21) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+22) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+23) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+24) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+25) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+26) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+27) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;

                    *(pixptr+28) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+29) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+30) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g;
                    *(pixptr+31) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_g += add_g;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Double pixel it
                    add_u <<= 1;
                    add_v <<= 1;

                    *(pixptr) = *(pixptr+1) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+2) = *(pixptr+3) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+4) = *(pixptr+5) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+6) = *(pixptr+7) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+8) = *(pixptr+9) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+10) = *(pixptr+11) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+12) = *(pixptr+13) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+14) = *(pixptr+15) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+16) = *(pixptr+17) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+18) = *(pixptr+19) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+20) = *(pixptr+21) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+22) = *(pixptr+23) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+24) = *(pixptr+25) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+26) = *(pixptr+27) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;

                    *(pixptr+28) = *(pixptr+29) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_u += add_u;
                    start_v += add_v;
                    start_g += add_g2;
                    *(pixptr+30) = *(pixptr+31) = depthq_table[(start_g>>16)][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16) ) ];
                    start_g += add_g2;
                }

                pixptr += 32;
            }

            if (!x)
                continue;

            // Do the odd bit at the end
            scale = 256.0f/dataptr->OOZright;

            start_u = end_u;
            end_u = (int)(dataptr->UOZright*scale);
            add_u = (end_u-start_u)/x;

            start_v = end_v;
            end_v = (int)(dataptr->VOZright*scale);
            add_v = (end_v-start_v)/x;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Special case for spans of 32 pixels or less */
            start_g = dataptr->Gleft;
            add_g = (dataptr->Gright-start_g) / x;

            scale = 256.0f/dataptr->OOZleft;
            start_u = (int)(dataptr->UOZleft * scale);
            start_v = (int)(dataptr->VOZleft * scale);

            scale = 256.0f/dataptr->OOZright;
            end_u = (int)(dataptr->UOZright * scale);
            end_v = (int)(dataptr->VOZright * scale);

            add_u = (end_u-start_u)/x;
            add_v = (end_v-start_v)/x;

            pixptr = lineptr + start_x;
        }

        /* Do bits of span less than 32 pixels */
        if ((ABS(add_u) + ABS(add_v)) & SINGLE_MASK)
        {
            /* Single pixel it */
            for ( ; x>1; x-=2, pixptr+=2)
            {
                pixptr[0] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
                start_u += add_u;
                start_v += add_v;
                start_g += add_g;
                pixptr[1] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
                start_u += add_u;
                start_v += add_v;
                start_g += add_g;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Double pixel it */
            add_u <<= 1;
            add_v <<= 1;
            add_g2 = add_g<<1;

            for ( ; x>1; x-=2, pixptr+=2)
            {
                pixptr[0] = pixptr[1] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
                start_u += add_u;
                start_v += add_v;
                start_g += add_g2;
            }
        }

        if (x)
            pixptr[0] = depthq_table[start_g>>16][ *(tptr + ((start_v>>16)<<8) + (start_u>>16)) ];
    }
}



// FP divide in parallel with the pixel drawing this idea got very popular with John Carmack's Quake engine. The ratio of pixels per FP divide in Quake is tuned to the integer-to-FP performance ration of the Pentium processor, which is one of the reasons that Quake I performs best on original Intel processors. This does not mean this code is the quake engine, but it seems to be inspired by it.

Indeed; Descent did perspective-only-every-n earlier, and with a bigger n, but I don’t think it was to exploit both Pentium pipes at once because it’s a little early for that. Probably just to cut down on divides.

What is the game?

Looks like OP has been given a code analysis assignment.

I would suggest reading this book by Michael Abrash as a good source for graphics engine-related questions for Doom/Quake era games.

VtC - SO, not RC.

depthq_table[x][y] appears to map from an input colour, y and a depth, x to an output colour. It might have been built in any number of ways, but a brute-force search will probably do: for each palette colour, figure out what colour it should be according to its depth (whether darker or lighter or according to whatever other fog or light dropoff) then search for the nearest thing that's actually in the palette.
gtmap_persp32_fp does what it promises to do; it calculates perspective-correct texture coordinates (u and v) once every 32 pixels in the main body of the loop, then in the inner part – the unrolled section in the middle full of parts that look like *(pixptr+<something>) = depthq_table[some][stuff] — it outputs 32 pixels by linearly interpolating from one perspective-correct calculation to the next. Note in particular the add_u = (end_u-start_u)>>5; and its equivalent for v which are seeding amounts to add per pixel by dividing the range to travel by the 32 steps that are to be taken.

Why need this section "Double pixel it"? #define SINGLE_MASK 0xffff8000 and what means if ((ABS(add_u) + ABS(add_v)) & SINGLE_MASK)?

@black4 it means that if the amount by which (u, v) should change per pixel is less than a certain threshold (as approximated in Manhattan distance) then instead of each pixel being unique, each is output twice consecutively. So as though horizontal resolution within the bounds of the triangle were halved, but only where the original texture is being scaled up a decent amount.
